# How to rotate a SKPhysicsBody like a wheel

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

My goal is to rotate a circular node like a wheel driven by a motor, e.g. when rotating clockwise the wheel will move right due to friction of the floor.

According to other threads the way to rotate a SKPhysicsBody is to rotate the body it is attached to.

This code rotates the sprite but not the physicsbody. How do I solve this problem?

```
let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ”circle")
circle.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.9)
circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.frame.width/2)
if let physics = circle.physicsBody {
    physics.affectedByGravity = true
    physics.allowsRotation = true
    physics.restitution = 0.2
    physics.friction = 1.0
    physics.isDynamic = true;
    physics.mass = 10
}
addChild(circle)
let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi, duration: 1.0)
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(rotateAction)
circle.run(repeatAction)
```

PS. This way of creating the body is not working in iOS 13 but should not affect the outcome.

```
circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: ”circle"), size: circle.size)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Why do you say the physics body isn’t rotating and as it’s a circle, how would you know if it was? If you are expecting the sprite to automatically move just like a wheel then it won’t - you will have to calculate to speed of a point on the circumference of the PB and move the sprite by that much yourself.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have created an edge based body around the scene. The circle falls to the bottom and bounces before coming to a halt. My goal is for the friction against the floor to make it move due to the rotation (edited the question with this information). Perhaps this is not how Sprite kit works?

Comment: Ok. So is it possible to do this (roll a body along the floor and other objects)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While moving or rotating a sprite directly will move the physics body too, the physics engine is there to move the sprites for you so that you don't have to worry about it.  The philosophy is to let it do the work rather than to add actions for creating the movements directly.

If you want a sprite with an attached body to rotate, either apply an angular impulse to the body (as suggested by Knight0fDragon) or just set the physics body's angularVelocity directly.  You might also want to set angularDamping to 0 if you don't want the rotation to stop.  E.g.,

```swift
...
addChild(circle)
circle.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
circle.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = .pi
...
```

Then remove the circle.run(...) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use ‘applyAngularImpulse’, not SKActions. Also set ‘allowsRotation’ to true

Comment: Ok, but how do I do this as a continuous motion?

Comment: Think about in in terms of real work physics... how does a car move?  It continuously applies force to rotate the wheels.